# vscode tailwind CSS how to have all colors in intellisense? (like `bg-sky`)

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, tailwind-css, vscode-extensions

**here what I see:**

- white
- gray
- red
- yellow
- green
- blue
- purple
- pink

### [image]

**but what I want to have too:**

> all these https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-color

- slate
- zinc
- neutral
- stone
- amber
- lime
- emerald
- teal
- cyan
- sky
- violet
- fuchsia
- rose

[image]

---

in the editor it didn't display it:
[image]

but for example red yes: [image]

Comment: First check what version of tailwindcss are you using, if you are using v2 and not v3 this is correct behavior since colors like `sky` did not exist in v2. If that's not the case check if you have intellisense plugin up to date.

Comment: @L.Letovanec so the v3 don't any different special color?

Comment: Here you can find colors that come out of the box in v2 https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors

Comment: @L.Letovanec yes, but it working in real browser, but ide not

Comment: solved, you need to use npm way, instead of cdn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get intellisense for these tailwind colors by importing and adding them to your default color palette in `tailwind.config` like so:

```
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors')

module.exports = {
  theme: {
    colors: {
      transparent: 'transparent',
      current: 'currentColor',
      black: colors.black,
      white: colors.white,
      gray: colors.slate,
      green: colors.emerald,
      purple: colors.violet,
      yellow: colors.amber,
      pink: colors.fuchsia,
    },
  },
}
```

For reference see https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#aliasing-color-names

You can also extend these colors if you want so that you don't have to add in every color to your defaults.

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        sky: colors.sky
      }
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: I saw now that if you use the CLI way so with npm install it automatically add it to the IDE, (and with CDN not). but if you don't use NPM way your solution it should work I think